# Ruby hash to json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

I have a ruby hash in my contoller

```
@my_hash = {
        name: 'Tokyo',
        data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
        }
```

When I use this in my js file

```
.
.
.
series: <%= @my_hash.to_json %>
```

I am getting `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token &`
The json object is like

```
&quot;{\&quot;name\&quot;:\&quot;Tokyo\&quot;,\&quot;data\&quot;:[7.0,6.9,9.5,14.5,18.2,21.5,25.2,26.5,23.3,18.3,13.9,9.6]}&quot;
```

how to get rid of `&quot;` when I use it in my js file? Any help much appreciated. I have been searching and found that this is a common issue.

Comment: JSON is just a text format. You want to get hash like you already have. Please, be more specific in your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you convert hash into json then you can use `.to_json` it will give you hash with `"/"` , in your case you can not use `.to_json`,Instead of this you may use `.as_josn`,It will convert your hash without `"/"`.
like:

```
<%= @my_hash.as_json %>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can also use *raw*

```
<%= raw @my_hash.to_json %>
```